# Regarding Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have saved the user Info and cart items in a database and i want to retrieve this information for a specific user.I am unable to target the user.

[image]

I have created child for user and each user has his  own uid. How can i target them?

Comment: If you understand Kotlin, this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-firebase-realtime-database-using-get-269ef3e179c5) will also help.

Answer (score 0):

To read and print the data for all users:

```
mDatabase.child("users").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.e("firebase", "Error getting data", task.getException());
        }
        else {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();
            for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                Log.d("firebase", String.valueOf(userSnapshot.getValue()));
            }
        }
    }
});
```

To read and print the data for the current user:

```
String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.e("firebase", "Error getting data", task.getException());
        }
        else {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();
            Log.d("firebase", String.valueOf(snapshot.getValue()));
        }
    }
});
```

All of this is based on the Firebase documentation on [reading and writing data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write) and [reading a list of values](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events), so I recommend spending some time there and possibly taking the Firebase [codelab for Android developers](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/).

Comment: Thankyou Frank, U were a great help to me...Love your mentorShip